# Could not find mysql2-0.3.11 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, passenger

I'm using Capistrano to deploy a Rails application on a staging environment. `cap deploy:update` works fine, but Passenger keeps reporting this
`Could not find mysql2-0.3.11 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

I did perform `bundle install`, `bundle list` and `gem list` both show the gem as installed and operations that require db access under `rails console` work fine, all of these on the server. On my machine everything is OK.

I'm using RVM, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.8 and this is the relevant part of deploy.rb:

```
set :rvm_ruby_string, ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"") # Read from local system
require "rvm/capistrano" # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.
```

Is it a Passenger issue, am I doing something wrong with Capistrano, or is it a problem with gem versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after I tried everything, I found out that the answer is as simple as:

`bundle install --deployment` (on the server)

This installed all necessary gems in the `vendor` folder of my app and everything works fine now

**Edit:**
Or better, in deploy.rb:

`require "bundler/capistrano"`